# Confusion about the Definition of Smooth Functions on a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am slightly confused about the definition of smooth functions on a smooth manifold given in *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring Tu (Second Edition, page no. 59). The definition is given below.

[image]

I am confused because I don't see how $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is, in general, defined. Let $\phi: U \to X$, where $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here, $\phi^{-1}: X \to U$. Then $f\circ \phi^{-1}$ is defined if the codomain of $\phi^{-1}$ is equal to the domain of $f$, which is not the case. Because the codomain of $\phi^{-1}$ is $U$ and the domain of $f$ is $M \supset U$. To my understanding, what we can define is $\left.f\right|_{U}\circ \phi^{-1}$, where $\left.f\right|_{U}$ is the restriction of $f$ to $U$. I am missing something here?

Comment: According to the definition $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is defined only on $\phi(U)$. So $f$ is automatically restricted to $U$ in this composition.

Comment: @AlexR. the domain of $f$ is a priori all of $M$. The OP objects to the string of symbols $f \circ \phi^{-1}$ being syntactically coherent. If for instance one is trying to write code this is not an unreasonable objection.

Comment: @hunter: Maybe I'm being dense but I still don't follow. $\phi$ is by definition invertible, so there shouldn't be any issues?

Comment: @AlexR. the probelmatic symbol for the OP is $f$, not $\phi$. In the OP's ontology, the data of a function includes a stated range and codomain, and composition only is defined if codomain(first function) = domain(second function). Since $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$, and $\phi^{-1}: X \to U$, the symbols don't stick together. One good solution is to relax the requirement on when composition is defined to just needing codomain(first function) subset domain(second function). (I mean "first" and "second" in the sense of order of application, not left-to-right, here.)

Comment: @hunter: but $U\subseteq M$, so I still don't follow why the composition is ill-defined.

Comment: @AlexR. the op's definition of composition is such that $f$ and $g$ can only be composed when the codomain of $f$ is equal, instead of a subset, of the domain of $g$.

Comment: @Alex R. I think that your criteria for a composition of functions to be defined are different than mine, where I have adopted Munkres's criteria (page no. 17, 2nd Ed). This is what exactly hunter mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, although your heart will be lighter if you will accept such notation when nothing is unclear, since the restriction symbol is bulky and hard to read.